# How to get objec it in Kendo Grid and pass it into button in gridrow

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, grid, kendo-ui

I'm trying to put a button into grid. In order to achieve that I wanted to use rowTemplates. However I have a problem with geting and item id and put it into action parameter.
So far I tried these  constructinos

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <form action="/Home/EditProduct/?id="+ "#=Id#" class="addEditButton" method="post">
                        <submit type="button" value="Edytuj"/>
                    </form>
                      </td>
                </tr>
    </script>

<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <form action="/Home/EditProduct/?id="+ ${ Id } class="addEditButton" method="post">
                        <submit type="button" value="Edytuj"/>
                    </form>
                      </td>
                </tr>
    </script>

<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <form action="/Home/EditProduct/?id=${ Id }"  class="addEditButton" method="post">
                        <submit type="button" value="Edytuj"/>
                    </form>
                      </td>
                </tr>
    </script> 

<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <form action="/Home/EditProduct/?id=${ Id }  class="addEditButton" method="post">
                        <submit type="button" value="Edytuj"/>
                    </form>
                      </td>
                </tr>
    </script>
```

However non of this method can successfully retrieve value of id parameter from object bounded to row. Is it possible to somehow pass value of id into action ??

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer your question.

http://andregelderblom.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/pass-kendoui-datagrid-variable-to-template-that-uses-zend-url/